# Disable text change in spinner

Tags: android, spinner

When I click on item inside dropdown list in spinner view in Android - the value on spinner is changed to the one i clicked. 
I would like to disable this behavior. 
I just need the callbakck, that such click occur. Any ideas?
Thanks Dominik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `getView()` method of your `Adapter`. Set the same text for all positions.